# Can someone please help me transfer Facebook business page ownership?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to transfer a business page ownership to one of the admin's on the page. I can no longer be the owner. It seems impossible to do. Can anyone help me? Or tell me how I can get in contact with Facebook? It seems crazy they promote Facebook advertising so much but there is no tech support team.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the other person to whom you want to transfer the ownership is your FB Friend or has liked your page.
2. Then open your page and go to 'Edit Page' -> 'Page roles' -> 'Assign a new Page role', enter the email of that person and then click on drop down near it, which has 'Editor' selected by default and change it to 'Admin' and click on 'Save'.
3. That's it. Now that person has the ownership of the page. If you want to remove yourself from the admin role just click on 'Edit' button under 'Existing Page roles' section and then click on 'Remove' link beside the 'Cancel' & 'Save' buttons.